# install from yocto recipe not able to create init.d folder

Tags: yocto, systemd, tpm, yocto-recipe, sysv

In yocto tpm2 recipe the following recipe is not workin fine:

`install -d "${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d"`

It's not able to create a folder named `init.d`. If I change folder name to `init_d` it is able to create the folder.
It appears strange to me becuase `init.d` is a very common in Linux and it's present under `etc` and I guess many recipes in Ycoto are doing this.
If I execute the command as `install -d /home/builduser/build/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/tpm2-abrmd/2.4.1-r0/image/etc/init.d` from terminal it creates the folder correctly where if should have created from inside the recipe also when run by bitbake command. I can see this command executed if I run `bitbake` with `-v` option.

Original code for recipe is here : https://gitlab.com/akuster/meta-security/-/blob/master-next/meta-tpm/recipes-tpm2/tpm2-abrmd/tpm2-abrmd_3.0.0.bb#L42

installing tpm2-tools using meta-tpm2 layer in yocto.

Answer (score 1):

Tthe folder is indeed created. However, the recipe also inherits the `systemd` class. This class will delete `/etc/init.d` to prevent duplicating systemV and systemd units when `DISTRO_FEATURES` contains `systemd`. See `rm_sysvinit_initddir` in [systemd.bbclass](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/plain/meta/classes-recipe/systemd.bbclass):

```py
python rm_sysvinit_initddir (){
    import shutil
    sysv_initddir = oe.path.join(d.getVar("D"), (d.getVar('INIT_D_DIR') or "/etc/init.d"))

    if bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'systemd', True, False, d) and \
        not bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'sysvinit', True, False, d) and \
        os.path.exists(sysv_initddir):
        systemd_system_unitdir = oe.path.join(d.getVar("D"), d.getVar('systemd_system_unitdir'))

        # If systemd_system_unitdir contains anything, delete sysv_initddir
        if (os.path.exists(systemd_system_unitdir) and os.listdir(systemd_system_unitdir)):
            shutil.rmtree(sysv_initddir)
}
```

You should not use legacy `/etc/init.d` scripts together with `systemd` in your `DISTRO_FEATURES`. You have to choose between systemd and systemV and setup `DISTRO_FEATURES` in your `distro.conf` accordingly. If you plan on keeping the older systemV init manager, then remove `systemd` from `DISTRO_FEATURES`. Otherwise, drop `/etc/init.d` in favor of `/lib/systemd/` units.

Note: systemd has compatibility with `/etc/init.d` but it is not recommended in production. It produces a warning. If you have another recipe which provides only `init.d` files, do not `inherit systemd` in that recipe.